# CS50 Speller segfault

Tags: c, hashtable, cs50

i can't seem to understand where the segmentation fault is coming from. my understanding of a hashtable is that you calculate a hash value for the input ( a string in this case ) and use the said value as the index for the table, allowing you to check if the input exists instantly without actually searching for it. here's my code for the hash function:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
}
node;
// set a size for the hash table
const unsigned int N = 100049;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    if (table[hash(word)] != NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{

    unsigned int hash_value = 7;
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
       hash_value = word[i] * hash_value;
    }

    return hash_value % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        table[j] = NULL;
    }
    FILE *infile = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    char *word = NULL;
    while (fscanf(infile, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new_node == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int hash_value = hash(word);
        table[hash_value] = new_node;
        strcpy(new_node->word, word);
        wordc ++;

    }

    fclose (infile);

    return true;
}
```

it compiles just fine but using the small dictionary and small text i get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

thanks in advance

Comment: `char *word = NULL;` Where is the storage for the words being loaded??? (PS: It's likely there will be an arithmetic overflow in your hashing calculations... This may result in a duplicate index being used... unsuccessfully. This would result in memory leaks...)

Comment: PS: Your "hashing function" will calculate the same value for both "live" and "evil"... Multiplication is commutative...

Comment: Your question is fine here, but if you're looking for a more focused c250 resource you could check out https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ too.

Comment: Kind of alluded to but not directly said, you haven't allocated any space for `word`, as soon as you write data to it with `fscanf` you invoke undefined behavior. Try something like `char word[256];` instead.

Comment: `wordc` also isn't declared in what you've posted. Questions with [mre]'s are _so_ much better..

Answer (score 1):

Code has at least these problems:

**Invalid `fscanf()` call**

The following passes an invalid pointer to store the *string* via `"%s"` resulting in *undefined behavior* (UB).

```
char *word = NULL;
while (fscanf(infile, "%s", word) != EOF  // Bad
  ...
```

Instead, pass a valid pointer to storable memory.
Also, do not use `"%s"` as it lacks a *width*.  Use a *width*.

```
#define STR_EVALUATE(x)   #x
#define STRINGIFY(x)      STR_EVALUATE(x)
char word[LENGTH + 1];
while (fscanf(infile, "%" STRINGIFY(LENGTH) "s", word) == 1) {
  ...
```

**Incomplete test**

Code only tests if *some* pointer is in the hash table.  Code should check if it is a matching string too.

```
// if (table[hash(word)] != NULL) {
size_t index = hash(word)
if (table[index] != NULL && strcmp(table[index], word) != 0) { 
  ...
```

**Weakness: hash should return a `size_t`**

**Weakness: hash should not return the same value with [anagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram)**